# Properties of Integrals Question

Tags: calculus

If $$\int_{-5}^{30} f(x) \, dx = 70$$
and $$\int_{15}^{30} f(x) \, dx = -30$$
then what is the result of the following?
$$\int_{-5}^{15} f(x) \, dx$$

Answer (score 0):

Please try to clean up your questions, but it would simply be $\int_{-5}^{15}f(x)dx$=$\int_{-5}^{30} f(x)dx $ - $\int_{15}^{30} f(x)dx $ =$(70-(-30))=100$

This is just using simple properties of the definite integral.

Answer (score 0):

First note that
$$
\int_{-5}^{30} f(x)dx=F(30)-F(-5)=70
$$
And
$$
\int_{15}^{30} f(x)dx=F(30)-F(15)=-30
$$
So now we have
$$
F(-5)=F(30)-70
$$
And
$$
F(15)=F(30)+30
$$
Therefore 
$$
\int_{-5}^{15} f(x)dx=F(15)-F(-5)
$$
$$
= F(30)+30- F(30)+70=30+70=100
$$